# Different Forms Of LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
string grid = @"08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08";
string[] res = grid.Split(' ');

var lowNums = from n in res
              where n.Length > 0
              select int.Parse(n);
```

I am having trouble converting the above linQ statement to a lambda WHERE equivalent. 
The following works, but only returns am `enumernable<string>` whereas I want an `enumerable<int>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> all = res.Where(x => x.Length > 0);
```

Comment: Good answers below; I just thought I'd mention that ReSharper 5 can do this for you, which you might find helps you learn the alternate syntaxes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am having trouble converting the above LINQ statement to a lambda Where() equivalent.

What you want to do then is carefully read section 7.16.2 of the C# specification. It will walk you step-by-step through the process.

It says:

> A query expression with a where clause

```
from x in e
where f
...
```

> is translated into

```
from x in ( e ) . Where ( x => f )
...
```

So your query

```
from n in res  
where n.Length > 0  
select int.Parse(n);
```

is translated into

```
from n in (res).Where(n=>n.Length > 0)
select int.Parse(n)
```

That's the first stage of the translation. Now go back to the spec again:

> A query expression of the form

```
from x in e select v
```

> is translated into

```
( e ) . Select ( x => v )
```

So your translated-once-already query

```
from n in (res).Where(n=>n.Length > 0)
select int.Parse(n)
```

is further translated into

```
((res).Where(n=>n.Length > 0)).Select(n=>int.Parse(n))
```

and now it is not a query expression any more, so no more syntactic translation is done.

Answer (score 9):

The following should work.  You just forgot the `select` clause.

```
res.Where(n => n.Length > 0).Select(n => int.Parse(n));
```

The `where` clause will not change your data into an `int`.  But, the `Select(lambda)` can.

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the call to int.Parse to convert the results to an int.  Since you're doing this after the "where" clause, this will require a Select(), which basically allows you to change the form of your enumerable (ie: map it to a new type, in this case, convert from string to int):

```
var lowNums = res.Where(n => n.Length > 0).Select(n => int.Parse(n));
```

Comment: I wish answers were still sorted by age `:P`

Comment: @Justin: Our answers were only about 10 seconds apart - though I only left mine because I had extra "text" describing ~why~ this was required, that your answer (at the time) was lacking.  I'm still leaving this, though, as my description differs from yours (which is also correct ;) - and got a vote from me )

Comment: Yeah, I was comment on the fact that our initial answers were ~10 seconds apart and contained the same content.  Great minds think alike.